Fill this Sudoku variant so that the sums of numbers in the outlined regions are all different
Place numbers in the grid so that each row and each column contain all the numbers {1,2,3,4,5} (each exactly once) and the sums of numbers in the outlined regions are all different.

Attribution:  momath.org

I don't have an answer. But I imagine it will prove helpful that there are several dominoes and two monominoes.

Unique solution:

 

Reasoning:
To refer to cells easier, let the top row be cells A1-A5, and label further cells accordingly.
To start, notice that there are 9 groups consisting of at most 2 cells, with only 1 having non-adjacent cells (D5 and E4). To start, we want to show that the non-adjacent two group cannot have a sum < 10. To prove this, assume that it does. Therefore the 9 groups consisting of 1 or 2 cells must have sums 1-9. This forces:
A5 and E5 are 1 and 2 in some order,
The sum 3 group consists of 1 and 2,
The sum 4 group consists of 1 and 3 (2 and 2 requires 2 on D5 forcing no 2 on either A5 or E5, cont.)
The sum 5 group consists of 2 and 3 (Since 1 is in the corner, at most 2 more 1s appear on the outer ring. We already have 2 from 3=1+2 and 4=1+3, so 5=1+4 is impossible.)
The sum 6 group consists of 3 and 3 (all outer 1s are taken so no 1+5, all outer 2s are taken by similar logic so no 2+4)
Contradiction on 7 (no 2+5 since no 2, no 3+4 since no 3).
This means our initial assumption must be wrong, and so D5 and E4 must both be 5. Therefore the outer 'ring' of groups must cover 8/9 sums from 1-9. Things get a little tricky from here:
Notice that if 9,8,7,6,4 are all sums that appear on the outer ring, then 9=5+4, 8=5+3, 7=4+3 (5 is taken), 6=4+2. As 4 appears 3 times in 2-blocks around the ring, it cannot appear in A5 or E5, forcing 4=1+3. Since 3 now appears 3 times in 2-blocks around the ring, it also cannot appear in A5 or E5, forcing B5 and C5 to be 3 and 4 in some order.
Knowing this, let's look at what the B5-C5 group can be. 1,2 implies 2 3-sums; 1,3 implies 2 4-sums; so it must be (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4). Noticing that the 1-sum and 2-sum could only appear in A5 and E5, the first 3 of these force either sum 1 or sum 2 to not appear. As 8/9 of 1-9 appear, this forces all others to appear. Notably, this means 9,8,7,6,4 all appear, which, by previous logic, would force B5-C5 to be 3 and 4, contradiction, as we took the presumption that it was one of (1,4), (2,3), (2,4). Hence, the B5-C5 group is (3,4), and A5 and E5 are 1 and 2 in some order.
Now, assume a 3-sum (1+2) appears:
It can't appear in the top row as then A5 can't be anything
It can't appear in the bottom row as then E5 can't be anything
Hence it's either the B1-C1 group or the D1-E1 group.
It being the D1-E1 group forces the D2-D3 group to be 3 and 4, contradiction as the B5-C5 group sums to the same.
It being the B1-C1 group forces A1 to be 5 and therefore the D1-E1 group to be 3 and 4, contradiction for same reason.
Since all cases contradict, there must not be a 3-sum.
Hence, the sums 4,5,6,7,8,9 all appear. These force the dominoes (5,4), (5,3), (4,3) (as 5 is taken), (4,2) (as 5 is taken), (3,1) to all appear.
Notably, (5,4) and (5,3) both appear. The only groups these can be are the A1-A2, A3-A4, and B1-C1 groups. It can't be the A1-A2 group: It would imply the other has to be the B1-C1 group, forcing all of (A1,B1,C1) to be (3,4,5), meaning D1 and E1 are 1 and 2 in some order, making a 3-sum, contradiction. Therefore (5,4) and (5,3) are the A3-A4 and B1-C1 groups in some order. This forces A3 to be 5. If A1 is either 3 or 4, that would force D1-E1 to sum to 3, contradiction, hence it's either 1 or 2, forcing A2 to be either 3 or 4. Now that we know this, look at the C2-C3-D2 group:
Since (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) are all taken sums, it must sum to at least 11. Therefore it either contains a 5 or consists of (4,4,3), but that's a contradiction since then C2 is 3, D2 is 4, but A2 is either 3 or 4 and so can't be anything. Therefore it contains a 5 in it's group, meaning C2 is 5. As the B1-C1 group contains a 5, B1 is 5. This means both C1 and C5 are 3 or 4, meaning C3 is either 1 or 2. As the C2-C3-D2 group sums to at least 11, C3 = 1 -> D2 >= 5, contradiction. Therefore C3 is 2, D2 >= 4 -> D2 is 4. This means that A2 is 3, A4 is 4, C1 is 3. As both E2 and E5 are 1 or 2, E1 is 3 or 4, meaning E1 is 4. A1 = 2 -> D1 = 1 -> A1-A2 and D1-E1 both sum to 5, which is bad, so A1 is 1, D1 is 2. This makes the rest of the grid fill out simply:
A5 is 2
E5 is 1
E2 is 2
E3 is 3
B2 is 1
D3 is 1
B3 is 4
D4 is 3
C4 is 1
C5 is 4
B4 is 2
B5 is 3
and we're done.
